# OnetoMany not persist

Tags: symfony4

A user can create a projet in this projet there is lot a of personnages and lot of chapitre. Chapitre can have many personnages and personnages can be in multiple chapitre. And I have a form to add personnages add before by the user. But is not persist in the database

In the entity Chapitre I created a variable personnages OneToMany, so I don't know why is not work

Entity Chapitre

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Personnages", 
 mappedBy="chapitre")
 */
private $personnages;
```

Chapitre controller

```
  /**
 * @Route("/addChapitre/projet/{idProjet}", name="chapitre_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 * @Entity("projet", expr="repository.find(idProjet)")
 */
public function new(Request $request, Projet $projet): Response
{
    $idProjet = $projet->getId();
    $chapitre = new Chapitre();
    $chapitre->setProjet($projet);
    $form = $this->createForm(ChapitreType::class, $chapitre);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($chapitre);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('projet_show', [
            'id' => $idProjet,
            'projet' =>$projet
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('chapitre/new.html.twig', [
        'chapitre' => $chapitre,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'projet' => $projet,
    ]);
}
```

The form is great I can select personnages but when I submit is not add in the database. And In my bdd I don't have and field personnages. My doctrine schema is good.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay I found the issue, I change ManyToOne in ManyToMany and it's okay beaucoup mane chapitre can have many personnage and the same in other directio.